# How to group by external values ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to run this query :

```
SELECT count(statistics.user_id) as y, YEAR('created_time') as t 
WHERE   ....
GROUP(YEAR('created_time'))
```

the query run perfect ! but the problem it won't return rows for years that are not included in my database .
I want the query to return empty rows, for years that aren't included in my database ! for example from 1991 - 2015 ?

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "DateTime" table with data you need, or build it as a subquery:

```
SELECT  count(s.user_id) as y
        ,t.yr
FROM    statistics s
RIGHT OUTER
JOIN    (
                select 1991 as yr
        union   select 1992
        ...
        union   select 2014
        union   select 2015
        ) t
    on  YEAR(s.created_time) = t.yr
WHERE   ....
GROUP BY t.yr
```